# MySQL/PerconaDB & Apache/LiteSpeed Optimizations for Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, database, apache

I know it's very vague but this is more of a general question than anything as I cannot find a solid answer to my question.

I just deployed a new dedicated server and had the hosting management install Percona as well as LiteSpeed. The questions are:

1. I see a lot of Apache optimizations as far as Magento is concerned but since I installed LSWS Enterprise does the optimization configuration tips apply to LSWS as well? Should I do those that applies to my server environment?
2. Like question 1 - I had them install PerconaDB as well and I know there are a lot of MySQL tuning for Magento. Do those vanilla MySQL tweaks apply to PerconaDB as well? Or does PerconaDB has it's own configuration file that I should look in to?

Not sure if it matters but here's my server specs:
Xeon 4C/8T E3-1240V3
32GB RAM
120 GB Intel SSD
1TB HDD
1Gbps Uplink Speed

Answer (score 1):

On LiteSpeed part, make sure you have LiteMage module enabled in your license. And you can install LiteMage extension from [connect](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/litemage-cache-2.html). It's a full page cache for Magento. Comparing using LiteMage and without FPC, you will see 20X difference.